# How to get sprite size which was loaded by Resource?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I have some sprites that should be loaded via `Resources.load<Sprite>("filename")` because I want to change some display according to user's localization.

Since the sprite size will differ according to the different language, I want to get the size of sprite and setting the sprite render's size to fix the actual size of the sprite. But I couldn't find an API properly for this task. the

`sprite.bounds.size.x/y/z` will give a unity unit instead of the pixel size.

```
    ui2dSprite.sprite2D = mySprite;
    ui2dSprite.width = (int)(mySprite.bounds.size.x * 100);
    ui2dSprite.height = (int) (mySprite.bounds.size.y * 100);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using Sprite.rect to get the actual size of the sprite's texture in pixels.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.html